# Voyager admin panel links are broken

Tags: laravel, routes, voyager

What is my problem: I make application using Laravel 5.5. I want had my application url like `www.example.com/shop`, and navigation in dashboard voyager panel are broken. Links goes to `www.example.com/admin/{slug}` instead `www.example.com/shop/admin/{slug}`.

Iv tried already change prefix routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop/admin'], function () {

     Voyager::routes();
});
```

then navigation links goes to `www.example.com/shop/{slug}` but admin panel href change to `www.example.com/shop/shop/...`

I changed APP_URL to `www.example.com/shop` in `env.`

I won't change links using static href in menus builder cos many application use this same database.

Comment: This is a known bug (I am the author of the Github issue). https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3993 https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/pull/4008

Answer (score 0):

I think your APP_URL should be www.example.com (without /shop). Try to run `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan route:list` and see what URI's you get.